# R Shiny's shinyalert "X" image issue

Tags: r, shiny, shinyalert

I am working on an R shiny app that uses shinyalert to inform the user of errors. The function works great, but for some reason the "X" image is distorted. I'm assuming this is a possible css issue.
Hoping someone can shed some light on this issue and possible solutions!

Code:

```
shinyalert::shinyalert(title = "Error!", 
                                       text = e$message, 
                                       type = "error")
```

Screen shot:

[image: 1]]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you think it would help the question to be answered if you made your question reproducible?  Have a look at: [mre]

Comment: Does this happen when you run a small example app from the package: https://github.com/daattali/shinyalert#overview